# Somar valores dos campos em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Possuo o seguinte HTML

```
<legend>Credits</legend>
<div id="credit-after">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[0][amount]" name="credit[0][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="25,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[0][cdate]" name="credit[0][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-09">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Details</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[0][details]" name="credit[0][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="credit-transaction-edit"><i class="fa fa-plus icon-add"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[1][amount]" name="credit[1][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="20,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[1][cdate]" name="credit[1][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-04">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[1][details]" name="credit[1][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[2][amount]" name="credit[2][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="10,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[2][cdate]" name="credit[2][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-04">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[2][details]" name="credit[2][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[3][amount]" name="credit[3][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="20,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[3][cdate]" name="credit[3][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-04">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[3][details]" name="credit[3][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="credit_total_rows" name="credit_total_rows" value="4">
</div>

<div id="amount_total">0.00</div>
```

Preciso somar todos os valores de todas as linhas. 
Porém, dinamicamente eu adiciono novas linhas abaixo com este jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.money').maskMoney();
    var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#credit-after"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".credit-transaction-edit"); //Add button ID
    var total_debit    = $("#credit_total_rows").val();


    var x = total_debit; //initlal text box count

    add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click

        e.preventDefault();

            $(wrapper).append('<div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money amount-credit" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="credit['+ x +'][amount]" name="credit['+ x +'][amount]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="credit['+ x +'][cdate]" name="credit['+ x +'][cdate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="credit['+ x +'][details]" name="credit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div>'); //add input box
            $('.money').maskMoney();

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field_credit_edit", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

De que forma eu consigo somar todos os valores e colocar uma div total?

Minha ideia é que ao listar, já abro com autosoma, e posterior ao editar qualquer um dos valores ou ao adicionar nova linha, faça a soma.

Comment: desculpe a pergunta, mas será desconsiderado os campos com data?

Comment: Sim, quero somar somente os valores que estão no campo amount, que seria o primeiro campo de cada div. E representar estes valores abaixo. :)

Comment: André, faça uma `function somaCampos()` que faça o trabalho de looping de soma e chama ela dentro das eventos de adicionar ou remover as linhas, assim quando vc adicionar ou excluir ele refaz a soma.

Comment: @WilsonFaustino entendi, só não sei como fazer isto. rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma função que faz a soma dos campos. Dentro da função você usa um `.each()` para percorrer cada campo com a classe `.money` e ir somando os valores, mas é preciso remover as vírgulas dos valores também:

```
function somaTudo(){
   var total = 0;
   $(".money").each(function(){
      // remove as vígulas e converte o valor para tipo Number
      total += +(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
   });
   $("#amount_total").text(total.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
}
```

A última linha da função insere o total da soma na div `#amount_total` com o formato americano, que é o formato que você está usando.

E para alterar a soma de forma dinâmica, basta usar um listener `onkeyup` que chama a função:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".money", somaTudo);
```

Comment: A unica coisa que estou estranhando é ele exibir 1, na frente do valor...

Comment: Como assim?....

Comment: Já consegui detectar, é que na minha tela tinha mais itens com a classe money, mas já alterei. Obrigado, deu certinho.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que você faça a `function somaCampos()`, como abaixo:

```js
function somaCampos(){
    var total = 0;
    $('div#credit-after input[type="text"]').each(function(){ //Você pode identificar melhor os inputs a serem somados aqui!
        let val_input = $(this).val();
        val_input.split(',').join(''); //Limpar os campos - separador de decimal tem que ser o (.)
        total += parseFloat(val_input);
    });

    $('div#amount_total').html(total);
}

somaCampos(); //Soma inicial
```

Deste modo, seus eventos de adicionar e remover ficariam assim:

**Adicionar:**

```js
add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    $(wrapper).append('<div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money amount-credit" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="credit['+ x +'][amount]" name="credit['+ x +'][amount]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="credit['+ x +'][cdate]" name="credit['+ x +'][cdate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="credit['+ x +'][details]" name="credit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div>'); //add input box
    $('.money').maskMoney();
    somaCampos(); //resomar todos os campos
});
```

**Remover:**

```js
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field_credit_edit", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    x--;
    somaCampos(); //resomar todos os campos
})
```

Deste modo, quando linhas forem adicionas ou removidas, a `function somaCampos()` é novamente chamada para recalcular os valores.

Answer (score 1):

> **Fiz os comentários nas linhas adicionadas.**

Você deve criar um função para converter esse formato `25,000.00` em um flutuante válido, como alguns amigos já fizeram aqui.

Como você estava adicionando um novo html, 
essa parte `<input type="text" class="form-control border-input money amount-credit" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="credit['+ x +'][amount]" name="credit['+ x +'][amount]">` estava indo com `value` igual a "", então, dessa forma sempre ia dar erro no cálculo, porque ele ia tentar somar um valor do tipo string. Eu adicionei 0.00 a esse `input`por padrão, então funcionou perfeitamente.

**Tente este código:**

```js
 //Função para somar ao carregar a página
function somaCampos(){
 //Faço uma intereção na classe amount-credit
            var amount_credit = document.getElementsByClassName("amount-credit");
            //Cria-se uma variável para add os valores dessa classe
            var totalAmount = 0;
            //Cria-se um loop para interar na classe amount-credit e pegar todos seus 
            //respectivos os valores
            for(let k = 0; k < amount_credit.length; k++){
              
              let value = amount_credit[k].value.split(',').join('');

              totalAmount += parseFloat(value);
            }
          //Mostra o valor total:
            $("#amount_total").html(`R$ ${totalAmount.toFixed(2)}`);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.money').maskMoney();
    var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#credit-after"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".credit-transaction-edit"); //Add button ID
    var total_debit    = $("#credit_total_rows").val();
    
    //Mostra os valores somados:
    somaCampos();
    
    var x = total_debit; //initlal text box count

    add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click

        e.preventDefault();

            $(wrapper).append('<div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money amount-credit" placeholder="Amount" value="0.00" id="credit['+ x +'][amount]" name="credit['+ x +'][amount]"x></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="credit['+ x +'][cdate]" name="credit['+ x +'][cdate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="credit['+ x +'][details]" name="credit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div>'); //add input box
            $('.money').maskMoney();
            
            //Faço uma intereção na classe amount-credit
            var amount_credit = document.getElementsByClassName("amount-credit");
            //Cria-se uma variável para add os valores dessa classe
            var totalAmount = 0;
            //Cria-se um loop para interar na classe amount-credit e pegar todos seus 
            //respectivos os valores
            for(let k = 0; k < amount_credit.length; k++){
                // console.log(amount_credit[k].value);
              let value = amount_credit[k].value.split(',').join('');

              totalAmount += parseFloat(value);
            }
            //Mostra o valor total:
            //console.log(totalAmount);
            $("#amount_total").html(`R$ ${totalAmount.toFixed(2)}`);


    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field_credit_edit", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<button class="credit-transaction-edit btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
<div id="amount_total">0.00</div>
<legend>Credits</legend>
<div id="credit-after">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[0][amount]" name="credit[0][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="25,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[0][cdate]" name="credit[0][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-09">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Details</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[0][details]" name="credit[0][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="credit-transaction-edit"><i class="fa fa-plus icon-add"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[1][amount]" name="credit[1][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="20,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[1][cdate]" name="credit[1][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-04">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[1][details]" name="credit[1][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[2][amount]" name="credit[2][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="10,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[2][cdate]" name="credit[2][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-04">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[2][details]" name="credit[2][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money disabled-inputs amount-credit" id="credit[3][amount]" name="credit[3][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="20,000.00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[3][cdate]" name="credit[3][cdate]" placeholder="Date" value="2019-10-04">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-input disabled-inputs" id="credit[3][details]" name="credit[3][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id='credit-transaction-edit'>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove_field_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="credit_total_rows" name="credit_total_rows" value="4">
</div>
```

Comment: Minha ideia é que ao listar, já abro com autosoma, e posterior ao editar qualquer um dos valores ou ao adicionar nova linha, faça a soma.

Comment: Fiz uma edição, veja aí.

Comment: Quase isso, porém, se eu alterar o valor, não dá o resultado que eu espero, e também se eu acrescentar valores tipo 500,000,000.00 não somaria corretamente. :/

Comment: No seu exemplo, cada vez que eu clico no btn add, ele mostra um valor diferente, e o resultado deveria ser 75,000.00 dessa forma, como a soma. certo?

Comment: Isso, mas é porque 75,000.00 não é um valor válido. Você deve convertê-lo antes de fazer a soma.

Comment: Sim e depois converter novamente para o formato original?

Comment: Até usei este formato que me passou, mas na hora de incluir novo campo não soma e na hora de alterar o valor também não atualiza. :(

Comment: Pronto, faça o teste, por favor.